# Hive partitioning using current date

Tags: hive, partitioning

I have some sample date like this

```
1,prasad,Newyork
2,Tarak,Mexico
```

I want to load this data in to hive table using partition using current date and when I load this data tomorrow again it should be partitioned by using tomorrow's date.

is this possible to achieve this in hive.????

Answer (score 0):

Use hive in **current_date** fucntion to generate the current date

```
hive> select current_date;
+-------------+--+
|     _c0     |
+-------------+--+
| 2018-06-18  |
+-------------+--+
```

Your Insert query would be

```
Insert into <db_name>.<target_tab_name> partition(<field_name>) select *,current_date from <db_name>.<source_tab_name>
```

By using the above query when you are loading the data to target table the date would be changing dynamically.